# How to set each div to specific coordinates jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have UI with div elements and i want to set this div object to some coordinates.

For now i can't find some method how to setobject to cordinates, but i have div objects.

I want to put this boxes to cordinates, what is betted solution to do this?

For example: `lpms3-box` set to cordinates `10, 50`

```css
.lpms3-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 150px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.machine-icon {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 90px;
}

.machine-icon>img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 40%;
}

.title-box {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 12%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lpms3-box">
  <div class="machine-icon">
    <img src="https://www.creativefabrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Coffee-Machine-icon-by-masbay02-580x435.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="title-box">Some title</div>
  <div class="desc-box">Some description</div>
</div>
<div class="lpms3-box">
  <div class="machine-icon">
    <img src="https://www.creativefabrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Coffee-Machine-icon-by-masbay02-580x435.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="title-box">Some title</div>
  <div class="desc-box">Some description</div>
</div>
<div class="lpms3-box">
  <div class="machine-icon">
    <img src="https://www.creativefabrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Coffee-Machine-icon-by-masbay02-580x435.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="title-box">Some title</div>
  <div class="desc-box">Some description</div>
</div>
<div class="lpms3-box">
  <div class="machine-icon">
    <img src="https://www.creativefabrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Coffee-Machine-icon-by-masbay02-580x435.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="title-box">Some title</div>
  <div class="desc-box">Some description</div>
</div>
<div class="lpms3-box">
  <div class="machine-icon">
    <img src="https://www.creativefabrica.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Coffee-Machine-icon-by-masbay02-580x435.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="title-box">Some title</div>
  <div class="desc-box">Some description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need JS for this. You can use CSS `position: absolute` then set `left: 10px; top: 50px;` on the target div to position it as required

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display to `fixed` on the wanted div,
then you can set top and left properties.

```css
.lpms3-box {
    ...
    display: fixed;
}
```

```js
function moveElement(x, y) {
    $(".lpms3-box").css({
        left: x,
        top: y
    });
}
```

EDIT:
If you want your div to be relative to it parent, use a `absolute` display inside a `relative` parent.

Comment: This is for one object but i want to set each object to specific cordinates

Comment: Can u provide some example?

Comment: `<div id="lpms3-box-1" class="lpms3-box">` and then use the id

Comment: What about Vanila.js?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="lpms3-box-1" class="lpms3-box">
    ...
</div>
<div id="lpms3-box-2" class="lpms3-box">
    ...
</div>
<div id="lpms3-box-3" class="lpms3-box">
    ...
</div>
```

```css
.lpms3-box {
    ...
    display: fixed;
}


#lpms3-box-1 {
   top: 10px;
   left: 50px;
}
#lpms3-box-2 {
   top: 400px;
   left: 250px;
}
#lpms3-box-3 {
   top: 600px;
   left: 50px;
}
```

or via Js

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".lpms3-box")).forEach(el => {
   switch (el.getAttribute("id")) {
       case "lpms3-box-1":
           el.style.top = "10px";
           el.style.left = "50px";
           break;
       case "lpms3-box-2":
           ...
   }
});
```

Comment: Cordinates i want to give from js, because i will have list if objects